# Wish : It will be great if you could add number of downloads in Office Store for an App

Tags: office-js

It will be great if you could add number of downloads in Office Store for an App so that end users can understand the popularity of the app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good idea! Please make this suggestion at [Office Developer User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).